# Upgrade from Angular 14 to 15 gives me build errors

Tags: angular, upgrade, angular15

This is currently my logging from an Angular build:

```
./angular/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Found non-callable @@iterator

./angular/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Found non-callable @@iterator

✖ Failed to compile.
```

But my polyfills and main.ts haven't really differed from the default implementation.
And the upgrade guide from Angular itself didn't mention editing the polyfill or main.

main.ts

```
import '@datx/core/disable-mobx';
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app/app.module';
import {environment} from './environments/environment';
import {init} from '@sentry/angular';
import {Integrations as TracingIntegrations} from '@sentry/tracing';

init({
    dsn: environment.sentry_dsn,

    // This enables automatic instrumentation (highly recommended), but is not
    // necessary for purely manual usage
    integrations: [new TracingIntegrations.BrowserTracing()],

    // To set a uniform sample rate
    tracesSampleRate: environment.sentry_trace_sample_rate,

    // Set the environment where sentry needs to post to.
    environment: environment.type,
});


if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

polyfills.ts

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js'; // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

(window as any).global = window;
```

I would have expected to have a build

Answer (score 0):

Have you aligned your Angular version with a compatible TypeScript version? It is marked as a breaking change. https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-15#angular-v15-supports-typescript-version-48-or-later

> Angular v15 supports TypeScript version 4.8 or later

`npm install -g typescript@latest` where `-g` is for `global`.

In case you need here are the steps to upgrade from 14 -> 15: https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=14.0-15.0

Comment: Thanks for the response.  

I have ran the yarn list command and the result for typescript is: typescript@4.8.4.  
Which is also defined inside my package.json devDependencies list.